# How to run EXE With admin privileges

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Im trying to run ShellExecute With elevated priveleges and it doesnt run the app.

`ShellExecute(0, "runas /user:Administrator", "C:\\installer.exe", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW );`

It should run the program as admin yet it doesnt even open it :/

Comment: Even if that was valid syntax, what if a user with that name does not exist?

Answer (score 2):

When using the "runas" verb with `ShellExecute/Ex()`, you can't specify a user account, that only works for the "runas" command inside of a `cmd.exe` command prompt window.

For `ShellExecute/Ex()`, you need to set the verb as just "runas" by itself, and then Windows will prompt the user for which account (and credentials if needed) to use for the launched process.

```
ShellExecute(0, "runas", "C:\\installer.exe", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: The runas verb works perfectly well, so clearly something else is wrong.

Comment: @DarkGhost you need to show your code. _I had tried that yet didnt work_: is not a very good descrition. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57748167/edit) your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong verb in the second argument. You should pass `"runas"`.